# window.open() opens a new IE browser window instead of native browser window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Button click from an MVC application calls window.open() method in javascript and it should open a new page with same browser but for me it opens in Internet explorer even if I am running the application from EDGE. How can I stop it opening in IE and force it running from my native browser